# Four columns, full screen overlay on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a situation where I have 4 columns that split the entire view. I'd like to implement a hover effect that occurs when the columns are hovered over.

I'd like each columns background to scale up slightly, but only within its allocated 25% (width) and 100% (height) area, but have one word related to that column appear vertically centered across the entire screen with a width of say 90% and a semi-transparent overlay color. This would have to not be affected by the 25%, 100% rule the background is restricted by.

I have tried and tried and can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: What have you tried? Mind posting some of the code?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not going to write the code for you, but I would recommend to do this you use JavaScript.

You could have hidden elements (for the centred text, with the properties you've described) which are positioned absolutely which then become visible once you've hovered over the relevant column. This is why you'll need to use JavaScript, to have an event listener on each of those columns and show the relevant centred text when hovered over.